# How can I add Two GestureRecgonizer in Single View

Tags: ios, objective-c, gesture

I have a small view (View Frame Size : 100,0,20,30), i want to add two gesture recognizer one is UIPanGestureRecognizer and another one is my own custom GesuterRecognizer "CPPinGestureRecognizer".

1. UIPanGestureRecognizer is used for drag the view in horizontally.

Example: the dragging bounds are :(100,0 to 320, 0)

1. CPPinGestureRecgonizer is used for enlarge the view in vertically with the same width.

Example: (enlarge view height up to user drag the view)

Now the problem is both gesture are working together and i want to check if the view dragged horizontally means want to fail CPPinGestureRecognizer, if the user dragged vertically means want to fail UIPanGestureRecognizer.

how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Gesture recognizers can have a delegate (`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`), and this protocol has 2 methods: [gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer%3ashouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer%3a) and [gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer%3ashouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer%3a). You can use those to not allow one to be recognized while the other one is currently being recognized.

Comment: how can i implement this delegate in my own custom CPPinGestureRecognizer.

Comment: but this both methods are available only iOS 7 and later, but i'm using iOS 5 for my project...

Comment: I did not realize that. You can use `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` in that case. That's probably a better method to use in the first place.

Comment: still its working both always. i want to make some gesture should get failed.